# error importing full path stored in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have two python files. Lets say `a.py`and `b.py` and I am trying to import some paths stored in `a.py` to `b.py`.

a.py

```
parameter_file_path = C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py

trace_file_path = C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.asc
```

b.py

```
from a import *
```

After running code in b.py I get error

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python-projects\PythonWork\a.py", line 1
    parameter_file_path = C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**What I want:**

I want it to just import both variables with path from `a.py` into `b.py` without showing any error.

**What I tried**

I tried changing the way I write this variables in `a.py`. I use the following code to write information to file

```
file = open('a.py', 'w+')

file.write('parameter_file_path = {}'.format(str(self.paraName.name.encode('ascii','ignore'))))
file.write('\n')
file.write('\n')

if trace_file:
    file.write('trace_file_path = {}'.format(trace_file.name.encode('ascii','ignore')))

file.close()
```

`self.paraName.name` = contains path name to parameter file

`trace_file.name` =  contains path to trace file

I tried writing this as a simple string and also using `.encode` as in above code but it makes no difference.

I also tried changing `C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py` to `'C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py'` manually in `a.py` and it works just fine. But even after lots of trying I am not able to store my path in string with single quotes just like above.

Comment: What is pathFile? I only see a.py and b.py in your question.

Comment: Well, `parameter_file_path = C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py` is invalid Python syntax. Either store those files as text files and read their content line by line or put the quotes. Since storing a path in a `.py` file is probably hard-coding it's better to keep those path lines in a simple text file and write a script that parses the parameters.

Comment: @SteveMisuta  I edited my question. While writing question here I was trying to keep format simple so used a.py and b.py names. I have changed it.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Okay I try doing it. Thanks

Comment: @EliKorvigo is correct. Those file paths need to be inside string quotes.

Comment: @Matt-SL I tried implementing quotes around that path but I was not able to implement it correctly. So I had these problems. I am now trying to import parameters in txt file. But still it will help me to put quotes around which i am not able to accomplish yet.

Comment: @Matt-SL you can't just `import` something from a text file, you need to parse it.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I am trying to parse parameters from `.txt` file and its going fine, but can you tell me how I should put single quotes around my string in `a.py` file which I write? This way it will minimize my efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a.py to be proper Python syntax you should specify the paths like

```
parameter_file_path = r'C:/python-projects/PythonWork/gen.py'
```

The r in front of the string is not necessary here because you only use slashes as path delimiters, but should be used when you write the path with backslashes.

Writing a.py can be done like this:

```
file.write("parameter_file_path = r'{}'".format(str(self.paraName.name.encode('ascii','ignore'))))
```